# What is a good spoiler-free lore resource that I can give to my party for the Storm King's Thunder adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, lore, background, storm-kings-thunder

I'm currently running a *Storm's King Thunder* campaign and got a question from a couple players in my party who wanted to create a backstory for their characters. They wanted to know more about the region that we are playing in, but they were afraid they might read up on things they don't want to know yet.

I have already looked into some sources such as [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/a9koto/i_made_a_spoilerfree_version_of_the_skt_world_map/) and [the Forgotten Realms wiki](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Nightstone), but these sometimes detail things about events that happen in a published adventure. So it isn't completely spoiler free. The same goes for the location descriptions that can be found in the published adventure book itself.

Does anyone know any resource or a way that I could let my players find a place in the setting of *Storm King's Thunder*, without having to worry possibly spoiling parts of the plot?

Comment: Are you asking about published adventures in general? Or SKT in particular?

Comment: SKT in particular, i've added it to the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide

Storm King's Thunder takes place in the Sword Coast and the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide describes all the places in the Sword Coast.

From what I can recall from reading it, it doesn't make any references to any of the published adventures, so it should allow you to read through without spoiling the plot, or at least with far, *far* fewer spoiler risks than any Reddit discussion or wikipedia page you'll ever find.

It also has the added benefit of being an official resource, so you won't run into any problems of people claiming things that simply aren't true.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, the book even specifies that it is intentionally unspecific about threats, encounters and plots, so I can give this to my players without any issues. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Jordi No problem, glad I could help. I've gone through it in the past while reading up on places as a DM, and I realized back then that it was pretty darn good for a player as well. One of my players actually borrowed it to read more about the places they're visiting.

Comment: @Jordi: You may wish to wait about a day or so to accept an answer in order to encourage other potential answerers to provide their own answers. :)

Comment: @V2Blast Okay, I'll keep that in mind for future questions. The answer posted by Theik was just exactly what I needed for my player, hence the quick answer.